# Is there a single-word noun for an overwhelming feeling that uses “overwhelm” as its root?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

Is there a single-word noun for an overwhelming feeling that uses *overwhelm* as its root?

My first thought was to make a gerund, that is, *overwhelming*. Although *overwhelming* is normally used as an adjective, this strategy applies to verbs like "cook", since *cooking* can be both a noun and an adjective.

That being said, I don't think I have ever heard *overwhelming* use as a noun, such as for example:

> The overwhelming was terrible.

Pardon the technical jargon, but that just doesn't sound right. Searching around [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=overwhelming) and elsewhere online doesn't yield more than people suggesting *overwhelming feeling* or [*overwhelmption*](http://www.girldetective.net/?p=4980) (although girldetective.net may not be an authoritative source on the English language).

Is there a single word that fits this use case? If not, why does such a word not exist? Is the verb *overwhelm* part of a certain class of verbs that don't lend themselves to this?

Comment: to quote an old hymn, "..'Neath the whelming flood...."  If you simply say "whelming" it carries the "over" meaning with it.  So go to the root:  An "overwhelming" feeling is in fact a "flood" of feelings.

Comment: @Bob That's certainly new to me! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OED includes these words as starting with “overwhelm‑”: *overwhelmed, overwhelmedness, overwhelmer, overwhelming, overwhelmingly, overwhelmingness, overwhelmment*.

It defines ***overwhelmment*** as “overwhelmedness; overwhelmingness” and gives these citations:

> - 1866 W. M. Thomas tr. *Hugo’s Toilers of Sea* II. vii. i. 90 — There is a degree of overwhelmment which abstracts the mind entirely from its fellowship with man.
> - 1960 Angling Times 9 Sept. 6/2 — Our river may cause love at first sight, a sudden instantaneous overwhelmment with its manifest beauty.

Note that *overwhelming* can itself be used as a noun.  Here is one of the OED citations for that:

> - 1883 *Athenæum* 4 Aug. 134/3 - A story of a sharp fight for existence and an ultimate overwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

I recently spotted "overwhelm" itself used as a noun, although the usage seems a little odd to me.
The line was:

> Climate change is a planetary emergency of overwhelming proportions. The challenges we face can be difficult even to think about leading to denial, overwhelm, or apathy.

Comment: I found similar use on Wikitionary: "The fact is, that full permeation and understanding of an overwhelm or trauma makes it cease as an overwhelm or trauma." [Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overwhelm#Noun)

Answer (score -1):

I cannot think of a generic word for an overwhelming feeling or sensation, but a good strategy is to up the ante on the feeling you intend to describe. Use a stronger word with additional connotations to do so.

- **Fear** — Try *terror, panic, dread, horror, fright*
- **Happiness** — Try *bliss, joy, elation, glee, ecstasy*
- **Tiredness** — Try *ennui, enervation, torpor, listlessness, indolence, languor*
- **Sadness** — Try *grief, misery, sorrow, gloom, melancholy, woe*
- **Anger** — Try *fury, rage*

In the case of your example, you want something that is terrible, so pick a feeling with some hefty negative connotations, and then replace *terrible* with another adjective that implies “overwhelmption”.

> - The dread was palpable.
> - I was crushed with woe.
> - Her glee was infectious.

Comment: So I take it that a word with "overwhelm" as the root doesn't exist? I was specifically wondering about that word (or class of words) out of curiosity, but synonyms are always an option of course.

Comment: I haven't seen a noun form of 'overwhelm' You could also try a more powerful verb `We were barraged by grief.`

Comment: Right, I know numerous synonyms for the feeling, but I'm mainly wondering about a) if one exists with that specific root, and b) if not, what is it about the word "overwhelm" that it doesn't have such a gerund?

Comment: It seems that [overwhelmedness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overwhelmedness) is a word, but it's cumbersome.

Comment: I’m not sure what counts as “counts as a word” in your book, but the OED attests all of these that begin with “overwhelm‑”: *overwhelmed, overwhelmedness, overwhelmer, overwhelming, overwhelmingly, overwhelmingness, overwhelmment*.

Comment: Answer does not fit the question.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure where I used the phrase "counts as a word" but all of those certainly qualify to me. I'll accept it if you post them as an answer.